# FileNotFoundException while parsing json in android 4.0.4 but works in android 2.3.3

Tags: java, android, http

I am trying to access the json that displays the contents of my android application. The FileNotFound exception is throwing in Android 4.0.4 but the json can be accessed in Android 2.3.3. The json can also be accessed from browser using the same url. What is wrong in the code ? Can anyone help me regarding this issue.

I am using the code below:

```
url = new URL("http://www.dynamiskdesign.se/ipromotionnew/json/148.json");

HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
httpURLConnection.connect();

InputStream input = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();

if (input != null) {
    writer = new StringWriter();
    char[] buffer = new char[1024];
    Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input, "UTF-8"));
    int n;
    while ((n = reader.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        writer.write(buffer, 0, n);
    }
    input.close();
}

String jsontext = writer.toString();
```

Comment: On which line is the exception thrown? Is there more info in logcat?

Comment: @RvdK No Logcat needed here. It is because: this error comes With HoneyComb(3.0 or Later). you can not perform a networking operation on its main thread as documentation says. to getting ride of this you must use handler or asynctask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the combination of network and threads.
Explanation is also on that page (link).
I had this too, look at this answer:
[httpclient (phpmyadmin) not working on Android 4.0+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13342638/httpclient-phpmyadmin-not-working-on-android-4-0)

I think this solution can work:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
//  
public class Connector extends AsyncTask<TextView, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(TextView... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return GetSomething();
    }

    private final String getSomething() {   
         try{
                url=new URL("http://www.dynamiskdesign.se/ipromotionnew/json/148.json");
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURLConnection.connect();
                InputStream input=httpURLConnection.getInputStream();

        } catch(Exception e) {
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
        }

        //convert response to string
        try{
                if (input != null) 
                {
                    writer = new StringWriter();
                    char[] buffer = new char[1024];
                    Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input, "UTF-8"));
                    int n;
                    while ((n = reader.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                        writer.write(buffer, 0, n);
                    }
                    input.close();
                }

        } catch(Exception e) {
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
        }
        //parse json data
        try {
                String jsontext = writer.toString();

        } catch(JSONException e) {
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
        }
        return returnString; 
    }    

    protected void onPostExecute(String page) {   
        //onPostExecute
    }   
}
```

Comment: The link you provided doesn't state anything about FileNotFoundException. Are you sure this is related?

Comment: @RvdK It is about my own experience. because network doesn't work on 3.0+ he can't find the `File`. I get a `NullPointer`, because it can't find a `String` on 3.0+. Here the problem is the same, but in this case it is a `File`, not a `String`. But the guy isn't answering back yet :p

Comment: @Bigflow Thank you very much :) I used Async task here and it works well.